# Looking for a file based on date created and the file type on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management

I am looking for a file on my PC, but I have no idea what it is called. All I know is its file extension and the date it was created. How can I locate it on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

The *Search* box is shown at the top right in Windows *Explorer*. Using Windows Search, enter

```
ext:<extension> AND datecreated:<date>
```

For example, to find an EPUB document created on Janauary 16 2022,

```
ext:epub AND datecreated:1/16/2022
```

Note that date does *not* have leading zeroes and is in m(m)/d(d)/yyyy format.

You can also use the less than and greater than symbols and search a range, e.g.,

```
ext:epub AND datecreated:>1/10/2022 AND datecreated:<1/16/2022
```

Other search fields are also available, such as *datemodified*, or even ones not often displayed, such as *authors* or *framerate*. See [How-To-Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/learning-windows-search/lesson5/) for more on advanced  Search syntax.

Comment: Top left? I see the search box only at the top right. Mind that "datecreated" is just for a field of that same name. Thus, if you have a German system and the column is called "Datum", you also need to search for "datum:" to filter that column, see also [How to search only files of a chosen month of a year in a huge folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1802924/how-to-search-only-files-of-a-chosen-month-of-a-year-in-a-huge-folder/1802925#1802925).

Comment: @questionto42, thanks, must have used RTL ;-) Answer corrected. And thanks for all the fish.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome physBa.

My goto for searching in Windows is an extremely useful tool/app called [Everything](https://voidtools.com/faq/).

> What is "Everything"?
>
> "Everything" is search engine that locates files and folders by
> filename instantly for Windows.
>
> Unlike Windows search "Everything" initially displays every file and
> folder on your computer (hence the name "Everything").
>
> You type in a search filter to limit what files and folders are
> displayed.

Simply type into Everything's search bar *.yourExtension and voila.

Using the View tab, select Sort by to refine your search by Date etc.