# How to search only files of a chosen month of a year in a huge folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, file-filter

I have a folder with 30 Gigabytes of media files in it. It takes hours to sort them by "date" to split them into new folders of "year_month". How can I search / filter out only a chosen month of a year in a large list of files?

##### Replying to answerers

In reply to the answer of adding libraries:

From [Show libraries in File Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-libraries-in-file-explorer-8b443cb0-e966-55d9-e0d3-f814fe2db95b):

> To show libraries in File Explorer, select the View tab, and then select Navigation pane > Show libraries.

If I arrange by day in the library:

[image]

I see only the same date 05.08.2023 in the "Datum" column of the library:

[image]

But I found out that this is also the same wrong date already in the Backup folder, therefore, the library cannot be better than what is in the data:

[image]

Even though I have an older screenshot from Ask Different Stack Exchange [Why do I have to retry copying many times and with many errors to move Gigabytes of image and video files from iPhone 7 to Windows PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462752/381223) (which made me ask this question here at all)

where you see that HEIC data had other dates in it:

[image]

But if I check the same data now, you see that I cannot get the HEIC images in the file list anymore, likely since I moved them to their right months. Anyway, if only 05.08.2023 is in there, only this date can also be shown in the library, and it is my fault if the HEIC files are missing

While the "Datum" column in the iPhone folder shown on Windows has the true dates in it, see the same files again:

[image]

This means that the backup has overridden the dates and that the library trick to make a quick indexed sorting by choosing "arrange by month" should work. That is why I accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the folder is indexed, you could create a new library from the folder. Although many dismiss Libraries, they offer `Arrange by >` functionality from the background context menu, which often provide all the search functionality you need.

The different library types or templates offer different `Arrange by >` options. For your needs, even though your files are media, use the `Pictures` template as it offers `Month` and displays "stacks" (virtual folders) for each month/year grouop as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Then, to copy/move your files, double click a stack to open it, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and copy/move as desired.

---

Edit: The `Arrange by >` options vary by Library type, which are similar to FolderTypes. If you're not seeing the choices:

- `Month`
- `Day`
- `Rating`
- `Tag`
  then your library isn't optimized for pictures. This can be changed via the Libary's `Properties` dialog:

[image]

This should work for you if, as I suspect, `Datum` is equivalent to the `Date` column in an English-laguage version of **Explorer**. It's a rather unique property,as it's neither a file system property ***NOR*** Exif metadata stored in the file, but rather a dynamic property determined by file type and whether or not metadata like `Date Taken` is present in the file. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1772327/881098) for more. As the linked documentation in that answer shows, the full property name is `System.ItemDate`, and that is the same propety a Library optimized for `Pictues` uses to stack by month:

[image]

---

---

Edit: Troubleshooting

---

Copy and paste this code into a **PowerShell** window to return the *Canonical Name* of the properties selected as the Sort columns in one or more open **Explorer** windows:

```
@((New-Object -Com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{ Echo ('{0}Window Title   :{1,30}{0}Sort Column(s) :{2,30}{0}' -f "`n`t", $_.LocationName, $_.Document.SortColumns)}
```

OUtput:

```
PS C:\> @((New-Object -Com shell.application).Windows()).ForEach{ Echo ('{0}Window Title   :{1,30}{0}Sort Column(s) :{2,30}{0}' -f "`n`t", $_.LocationName, $_.Document.SortColumns)}

        Window Title   :                      Pictures
        Sort Column(s) :        prop:-System.ItemDate;

PS C:\>
```

Execute the code in your pictures folder, then again after navigating to your Library. Are the properties the same???

Comment: Never worked with a library, good point. But I do not have the same menu, I can only arrange by "change date", marking, type, name, but I cannot arrange by date or month. When I arrange by one of the items of the menu, sorting is fast. But being inside the library mode, if I add the needed field "datum" to the fields of the explorer view, it does not pop up in the "arrange" menu, and if I sort by "datum" with a click on the field, it takes hours as before. Still these libraries sound good, and I guess that the library adds the needed index to some fields. I only need it for another field.

Comment: Sounds like your library wasn't optimized for pictures. See the edit to my answer for more...

Comment: I optimized it for pictures. But if I arrange by month, it does not check the property "Datum", but it takes one of the other, likely "Erstellungsdatum"/"Creation Date" or "Änderungsdatum"/"Change Date". Thus, if I then arrange by month, I get only one month which has all the pictures of any month in it. If I arrange by day, I get just one date in the whole "Datum" property, it is always just the date when I started this work, 05.08.2023, with all files in it. If I arrange by day, any "Datum" property is shown as 05.08.2023 even though they have another "Datum" without arranging by day.

Comment: I guess that your way of arranging it by date should normally work. But most of my date properties were mainly overwritten by the date when I pulled the backup from the mobile phone. That is why even the "Datum" property seems to be not the same as the `System.ItemDate` property that is chooses if you arrange by day or month.

Comment: Without knowing what property "Datum" is, since you say it's not `System.ItemDaate`, and it doesn't correspond to *any* of the date properties of the file(?!?), I'm at a loss.

Comment: If `System.ItemDate` is something else than "Datum", which can be seen from the way the "arrange by" works, I must change the metadata by overwriting the "Creation Date" or "Change Date" or perhaps another date property that I can find by "Datum", and arranging by month might work as you say it.

Comment: I thought of a way we should be able to determine the underlying *Canonical Names*  of these various properties so be certain which properties are in play. Its a **PowerShell** one-liner that will report the Canonical Name(s) of the SortColumn(s) selection. Adding as edit to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: `Window Title   :                        202204        Sort Column(s) :        prop:-System.ItemDate;` Which makes it even less clear. If the property is the one that should be "arranged by month", then I do not see how the full output of all of the files has just one "Datum" in it (05.08.2023) even though the files have a wide range of dates in "Datum" if I "arrange by folders" instead. Looks like a bug in the library tool.

Comment: Not a bug really, because that's the property designated as the `StackBy` property in the `TopView` definition in the registry snapshot in my answer. The `StackBy` aspect of a TopView isn't dynamic.

Comment: The files still have their filesystem and netadata dates. If you navigate *into* a stack, all the columns are available. Column choices*are* limited in a Details view of the stacks themselves.

Comment: To make this clear (but I think you already got that, just to be sure), in my new library with all of the pictures, I only see one month, August 2023, since all of the dates are read as 05.08.2023 even though there are other dates in the "Datum". But this is just not shown when I browse this "Datum" column in the library if "arrange by month/day". The true "Datum" dates are only shown if I "arrange by folder". And the other thing: if I check the registry, I do not get deeper than `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Windows\CurrentVersion`. I cannot check how the default StackBy is set.

Comment: I chose this now as the right answer since it is clearly the easiest way to get the monthly folders in a short time, indexed for quick work. My files are dated 05.08.2023, else the library trick would work well. I had a mess of data problems when I tried to get all of the images from the iPhone to Windows PC, also with a 3rd party tool, which led to a few misunderstandings of my own files.

Answer (score 2):

##### Search with [field:month year] pattern (works only for small samples)

Open the folder with the files that you want to filter out. In the search box on the top right, enter in your system language with the following pattern:

`[column name]:[month in letters] [year]`

Example in German:

- Jan 2023 / Januar 2023
- Feb 2023 / Februar 2023
- März 2023
- Apr 2023 / April 2023
- ...

Makes:

[image]

In the search menu, you can find many more patterns, like this month, last month, and so on, and if you click them, you will also see their code in the search box, ready to tweak it further:

[image]

So that you could click on "Änderungsdatum: letzten Monat" which is the "change date" of the last month (meaning not a month back in time, but the last calendar month):

[image]

And since I need it for another field/column than the "change date", I can change it to column "datum":

[image]

##### This does not seem to work with large lists of files

Strangely, this does not seem to work with all files, since my filter on "Aug 2023" with its output that I moved to the "202308" folder looks like this:

[image]

As can be seen by the few example images of that screenshot, I still find other images of other months, and it turns out that these are *all* of the HEIC and some JPG images (11500 out of 12000). Filtering inside this "202308" folder again, I get only "Aug 2023" images, thus, the filter somehow works in the search output, so that it may just not work when moving that huge and perhaps not fully loaded search output to a new folder?!
Then I thought, I might catch only the "datum:aug 2023" files when I do not press `Ctrl+A`, but mark the first to the last in that search output and move them only then. But in a test, when marking only the filtered files of the search output, the same number of files was marked as the number of files wich are in the whole folder, thus, you seem to mark *all* of the files in that folder even if its search output *must* have less files (since I know for sure that not all files in there were "aug 2023"). **And that means that the search filter cannot be taken to split a chosen month from the other, sadly. This answer is therefore not enough for big folders, it only works for smaller ones.**
I went on to filter out other months and moved them to their own year_month folder, but since I had all of the HEIC files in that "202308" folder, I did not find any HEIC images. Only a few MOV and JPG files were found by the filter:

[image]

I still went on to at least move those files that could be found so that the size of the big folder shrinked at least a bit. Now, I still need to sort the remaining 11500 files by "datum", which will take hours. Strange bug.

Thus, I still did not find a way to filter out those months of HEIC and other images from this big list of files, there are still ~11500 HEIC/PNG/JPG images out of ~12000 files in one folder.

##### Split by the file name

Since I had a folder in which all of my iPhones monthly folders were merged with a lot of duplicates in the names, I ended up moving each file with a "(2)" in it to a new folder, and went on with other markers like that, thus, starting the split by the name and then sorting the smaller sample (then just 1300 files) by the date column:

[image]

This worked, sorting did not take long anymore and I could then split these files into their monthly subfolders.

##### Move smaller samples of 1000-2000 files to another folder

But if you do not have something like the name to get to this, the only way to deal with this is to make a random sample of some thousand files or more, sort them by date, split them into the folders, and go on with the next sample. This is what I ended up with, and perhaps one should already start with this since it was quite quickly done, even if you had to move the files into the monthly folders dozens of times. At least, the computer could handle it.

##### Program it

I have dealt with files in Python a lot of times, and with the pathlib library, it should be easy to read the "datum" and move it to a year_month folder without anything to do by hand. I did not take the time, but should be the better way than moving around files into the right monthly folders hundreds of times.